# how to convert array to string?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm getting control text as an array and I want to pass this to $.post as string. I need suggestions on how to convert it to string.

```
var controlText = $("input[name='control_text']").map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get();
//alert(controlText);      
$.post("dbfile.php", {
    columns_one: columns_one,
    controlText: controlText,
    controlPara: controlPara,
    mandatoryValue: mandatoryValue
},
```

Answer (score 1):

You could join them with a comma:

```
var controlText = $("input[name='control_text']").map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get().join( "," );
```

Or json encode:

```
var controlText = JSON.stringify( $("input[name='control_text']").map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get() );
```